# Where does Cache get saved?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I saw this somewhere on the source code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("Something");
```

Where does the cache get saved and how do I view a list of element/value in the cache?

If I restart Windows Server and run IIS Server - does the cache get cleared or does it reload from somewhere?

Comment: [ASP.NET Caching - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: The cache is not durable.  A restart clears the cache.

Comment: It is a cache. Its contents can disappear at any time even without server restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you having here is `HttpContext` cache, which is available only if you run your application on web server. It is memory cache and it is not saved anywhere. So, if your computer reboots, or even if your web application restarts, this cache will be cleaned out.

If you would use `Enterprise Library` caching blocks, those have option for backup storage, so the cache can be re-activated from application startup.

If you want to see what is in your cache, you can use `GetEnumerator` >> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx